# Why Put is defined as a Persian Tribe

Tags: hebrew, word-study, history

In Strong's Hebrew Dictionary, Put (#6316) is describe as

> Of foreign origin; Put, a son of Ham, also the name of his descendants or their region, and of a *Persian tribe*

Put is described as a son of Ham in Genesis 10 (which is likely Libya), but I can't seem to find why it is described as a Persian tribe, neither in the Bible nor in history. Why did Strong describe Put like this?

Comment: I don't see how Put in Ezekiel 27:10 is a Persian tribe; it could very well be Libya like it likely is every where else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A multilingual [stele](https://infogalactic.com/info/Stele) from al-Kabrit (Saudi Arabia) dating from the reign of [Darius I](http://infogalactic.com/info/Darius_I) (550–486 BC) provides some of the modern confusion here (but it would not explain Strong as it was discovered long after Strong). The stele refers to Put (sometimes spelled Phut) in three languages. Both Old Persian and Neo-Babylonian connect Put with a region of Persian. However, the equivalence line of text in Egyptian places Put as part of Libya.

You are correct in that [most of the references](https://infogalactic.com/info/Phut) to Put indicate they were from the region we know as Libya. The Septuagint of Ezekiel uses *Libues* whenever the Hebrew has Put (27:10, 30:5, 38:5).

> 27:10 Men of Persia, Lud, and **Put** were in your army, men of war.
>   They hung shield and helmet on you; they gave you your splendor. (NET)
>
> 30:5 Ethiopia, **Put**, Lud, all the foreigners, Libya, and the people of the covenant land will die by the sword along with them. (NET)
>
> 38:5 Persia, Ethiopia, and **Put** are with them, all of them with shields and helmets. (NET)

Possibly, Strong placed Put as part of Persia because two of these three references link it with Persia (27:10 and 38:5). Likewise, Lud 
(27:10 and 30:5) refers to a settlement near the Tigres. However, 38:5 and 30:5 also link Put with Ethiopia, part of Africa. Obviously, all three cannot be linking them by geography. The places are linked for other reasons in these texts.

Josephus (*[Antiquities](https://infogalactic.com/info/Antiquities_of_the_Jews)* 1.6/2), Pliny the Elder (*[Natural History](https://infogalactic.com/info/Natural_History_(Pliny))* 5.1), and Ptolemy (*[Geography](https://infogalactic.com/info/Geography_(Ptolemy))* iv.1.3) all refer to Put as being west of Egypt. In addition, Ptolemy mentions a city named Putea in Libya (iv.3.39). Josephus writes that the region was once known as Put but the name has been changed to reflect the name of a son of Mezraim, Lybyos. Mezraim being the Hebrew name for Egypt.

Comment: What caused Strong to think that one of the refs to Phut was the persian tribe and not Libya? Did the Septuagint use a different word or something like that?

Comment: The Kabrit stele was not discovered until long after the time of Strong. So you cannot really blame it for the confusion.

Comment: @fdb, thank you. I was editing when you made your comment.